# Can you have a variable amount of variables in a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, variables, containers

This is my first question here, and I'm not very skilled at programming yet, so my apologies if I do something wrong. That said, I searched both here and on Google before asking the question, so if a duplicate exists, it's because I didn't know how to find it.

My question is as per the title.

I'm attempting to program a little procedural star system generator to refresh my memory and help grow my programming skills. I want to create a class for the solar system to hold data on the star(s) and planet(s), each of which will also be a class. So to illustrate my question for clarification:

Is there a way to avoid having to declare, say, 10 different "planetClass" items in the class, and instead define one that scales as it's needed? If not, is there an alternative, or do I just flat-out have to define up to the maximum variables needed?

Comment: You may look at `std::vector` or other container classes.

Comment: No, but you can have variables that are structures and contain other variables, and [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) which can contain a *variable* amount of such structures.

Comment: 1. [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) - 2. [Polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) - both might help you.

Comment: You should look into "memory management" for C++. That'll teach you the basics of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Dudeson: Memory management isn't needed that much anymore. `std::vector` will do it for you.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes it is definately needed. It will teach him the basics. After that everything will be just logical to him. Also, not everyone is allowed to use vectors.

Comment: Thank you all. "Memory Management" and "std::vector" gave me a good starting place, and I think I have what I need.

Comment: @Dudeson: `vector` isn't just allowed but expected in professional work. And when I hire people, a preoccupation with manual memory management is sufficient reason not to hire someone.

Comment: @Msalters: Look into game development. That's all I'll say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a `Planet` class to store data for each planet, and then add a `std::vector<Planet>` data member into your "outer" class.

`std::vector` is a standard STL container class template, that can be dynamically (i.e. at run-time) resized. You can add new items (in your case: `Planet` instances) to it, using its `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` methods.